# PowerBI - conditional formatting tips

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a matrix in PowerBI and the conditional formatting feature is just awful. Does anyone know of any tips/tricks to using conditional formatting in a matrix?

Specifically, I am trying to accomplish:

1. Hard-stop/single-shade formatting. In other words, I have my Minimum and Maximum values, and I want to color values inside that range a certain color. I don't want some values lighter than others.

---

2. I would also like to highlight weekends in some way so that I can tell if a value occurs on a weekend, but this is not as important.

Comment: conditional formatting in Power BI does not (yet) support that level of complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a custom visual. [This page](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-conditional-table-formatting/) is pretty helpful (click creating custom visuals in the navigation area)